# Extra white space when using BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm using Java Swing to make a simple GUI using a BoxLayout LayoutManager. It is basically composed of a single JPanel, with additional JPanels able to be added by the user.

With two JPanels (the first one, and one additional), the format is proper:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg9Wd.png]

But when even more JPanels are added, extra space is added to the left side of the frame:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSnFA.png]

Here's what I have:

```
public void updateListFrameContentPane(Container mainPane) {
    mainPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1+chatPanels.size()));
    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    firstPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(firstPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    firstPanel.add(friendsLabel);        
    firstPanel.add(listScrollPane);
    mainPane.add(firstPanel);
    for(JPanel chatPanel : chatPanels)
       mainPane.add(chatPanel);
}
```

Where `chatPanels` is a `HashSet<JPanel>`. I tried using the `setMaximumSize` method on each JPanel to allow them to grow larger but that didn't help. How do I get rid of the extra space?

Comment: do you mean the space at the bottom and to the left of the last panel added?

Comment: In my experience `BoxLayout` works better with a combination of `setMinimumSize()`, `setPreferredSize()`, and `setMaximumSize()`; all of which `BoxLayout` obeys to some fashion. Also, make sure you aligned all of the panels correctly using `setAlignmentX()` and `setAlignmentY()`. Also, adding `Box.createVerticalGlue()` and `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` appropriately to the panel containing the ones you're organizing can tell `BoxLayout` where to give the extra space.

Comment: Was not your intention to add chatPanels to mainPane instead of pane?

Comment: @GáborBakos Yes, I corrected it. That happened when I copied my code the SO and changed the variable names to be more clear